# Can TBE electrophoresis buffer be stored in a PETE container?

Tags: biochemistry, plastics

I'm doing a science project on agarose gel electrophoresis and would like to know if it is safe to store Tris/Borate/EDTA buffer solution inside a PETE container since I will be making about 10L of the buffer solution and do not have access to a spigoted carboy or any such container.

Comment: Are you planning to make 10l of 1x TBE? If so, make the solution 10x concentrated (take the ingredrients for 10l and dissolve them in 1l), than you can easily store your buffer stock in a 1l bottle. Dilute portions of it 1:10 to make the working solution. But you can also store 10l of working solution in a 10l container, we have such a reservoir in our lab.

Comment: Do you have glass containers? We've stored TBE in glass bottles for years with no problems. If you don't have a large glass bottle on hand, get some juice or something from the store, drink it, and clean that bottle out real good with distilled water.